# Grunt: Force Live reload to refresh at home page instead of current URL?

Tags: gruntjs, watch, livereload

I am using grunt. Under watch task I have livereload set to true. Whenever I make a change it automatically refreshes my browser at current URL. Is there anyway to force it to refresh it to home page instead of current url?

Answer (score 0):

If you roll your own livereloading in your gruntfile as described [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#rolling-your-own-live-reload), you can then trigger a reload of the homepage like this:

```
lrserver.changed({body:{files:['index.html']}});
```